# Reading key,value pair using batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to read a `config.properties` with 50+ key, value pairs and using all the keys in one of the invoked `.bat` files.

I already have a working code which reads the properties but then it prints `key=value`. I would like to return only the key value e.g.`john` not the key name.

**1.  main.bat**

```
set READER_FILE="C:\\read.bat"

@ECHO OFF    

: INVOKING CONFIG PROPERTIES
  call read.bat > %LOGGER% 2>&1
: call %READER_FILE%   

: call DownloadContent.bat > %LOGGER% 2>&1

 echo %name%
 echo %city%
```

**2. read.bat**

```
@echo off    

for /F "eol=# delims== tokens=1,*" %%a in (config.properties) do (

    if NOT "%%a"=="" if NOT "%%b"=="" set config.%%a=%%b
)

set config.

for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%v in ('set config. 2^>null') do (
    set %%v=
)
```

**3. config.properties**

```
name=john
city=NY
country=USA
```

Please let me know if I am missing any details.

Answer (score 2):

To `set` the `key=value` pair :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (config.properties) do set ###%%a
```

To display all value :

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set ###') do echo %%a
```

To display all key :

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%a in ('set ###') do echo %%a
```

To display key and value :

```
 set ###
```

or

```
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('set ###') do echo %%a / %%b
```

to display one specific element :

```
 echo %###name%
 echo %###city%
 echo %###country%
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another for loop to process the config. variables.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A ('set config.') echo %%A
```

That should output just the variable names that start with `config.`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it is working for me:

```
::Access config.properties file and read it as Key:Value
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%i in (Config.properties) do echo %%i:%%j

Output:
name:john
city:NY
country:USA

If you want to print only values, just remove %%i in above code:

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%i in (Config.properties) do echo %%j

Output:
john
NY
USA
```